# android app not closing when I click on home button

Tags: android, android-activity, youtube, android-webview

I have written webview on which there may be youtube videos. When I start video and press home button application closes (Goes in background) and I can still hear audio. Then I had to kill task manually (Using battary-doctor now !!)

I have tried onPause() and onStop() methods and tried to call finish() but it is not working.
I saw some questions where it is written it is not possible to override home button.

What I want to do is kill the activity once home button is pressed. If android is handling killing ... fine .. but just pause the youtube video and then go to background !!!

Can someone help ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than killing the activity, you should just clear the WebView. `onPause()` is called when the activity goes into background, so that's where you should attempt to "unload" the WebView.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
```

Comment: Cool !!! As android itself handling activity states after it goes to background.... this is perfect solution in my case. Thanks for quick reply !!!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: whre should I call this ?

Comment: in onPause if you want kill your app after home press

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    onDestroy();
}
```

**EDIT:** To be honest You should not try to kill apllication at pressing home button, but pause video at that moment. OnPause() method is a place where You should do.

Comment: I got msg when I pressed home button "unfortunately, APP has stopped". Dont want to see this msg. Want to finish it silently :)

Comment: I have one activity which have one webview and i set bolg url in which youtube video may exist.